# redirecting HTTP to HTTPS using filter not working

Tags: java, servlets, https

I want to redirect http to https, a solution I found is using a filter to do so, I have implemented the filter which is used to redirect http protocol to https
but when I try to open the site, i get google error, 
"Try:
Reloading the page
Clearing your cookies
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

am not limited to using the filter, if any other approaches can solve the above, please mention them

```
public class HTTPSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws java.io.IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        String uri = req.getRequestURI();
        String getProtocol = req.getScheme();
        String getDomain = req.getServerName();
        String getPort = Integer.toString(req.getServerPort());

        if (getProtocol.toLowerCase().equals("http")) {

            // Set response content type
            response.setContentType("text/html");

            // New location to be redirected
            String httpsPath = "https" + "://" + getDomain + uri;

            String site = new String(httpsPath);
            res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
            res.setHeader("Location", site);
        }

        // Pass request back down the filter chain
        chain.doFilter(req, res);

    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

web.xml

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>HTTPS</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.simsarak.filters.HTTPSFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>HTTPS</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I tried modifying the  .htacess file on the server, also tried adding the "<security-constraint>" to my web.xml , and finally using the redirect on cPanel but none of them worked

Comment: I have installed the SSL, and accessing the site using https://... is working fine, but i want to redirect the http to https

Comment: tried that too, but finally the server support team told me that it must be done programmatically

Answer (score 1):

Modify the filter as below. You don't need to set the `Status` and `Location header` as `response.sendRedirect()` should take care of it.

```
public class HTTPSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws java.io.IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        String uri = req.getRequestURI();
        String getProtocol = req.getScheme();
        String getDomain = req.getServerName();
        String getPort = Integer.toString(req.getServerPort());

        if (getProtocol.toLowerCase().equals("http")) {
            // New location to be redirected
            String httpsPath = "https" + "://" + getDomain + uri;
            //redirect
            res.sendRedirect(httpsPath);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```